# How do I empty global arrays used in a pop up slideshow?

Tags: javascript, arrays, slideshow

I've created a program where you can choose a set of images by checking checkboxes. The image URL's and the alt-texts are stored in two arrays. When clicking av button on the HTML-page you open a new window that calls on the arrays with window.opener.

When closing the new window I would like to empty the arrays. Otherwise the pictures chosen in the first round are displayed in the slideshow when opening it the second time. I understand you can empty arrays by this method:  array.length= 0;

But where do I add the code? I'm quite lost. I'm pasting the code, perhaps someone can give me a hand.

```
var imgUrlList = [], imgTextList = [], //These arrays need to be emptied
    windVar = null;

function init() {
    var tags, i, openWindow;

    tags = document.getElementsByClassName("unmarkedImg");
    openWindow = document.getElementById("slideShowBtn");
    openWindow.onclick = savePicsForSlideshow;
    for (i = 0; i < tags.length; i++) {
        tags[i].parentNode.onmouseover = showLargePict;
        tags[i].parentNode.onmouseout = hideLargePict;
    }
}

window.onload = init;

function showLargePict() {
    var largePictTagDiv = this.getElementsByClassName("innerBox")[0];
    var largePictTagParentDiv = largePictTagDiv.parentNode;
    var imgTag = largePictTagParentDiv.getElementsByTagName('img')[0];
    var checkBoxlargePict = largePictTagDiv.getElementsByTagName('input')[0];

    if (checkBoxlargePict.checked)
        imgTag.className = "markedImg";
    else imgTag.className = "unmarkedImg";

    largePictTagDiv.style.visibility = "visible";
} // End showLargePict

function hideLargePict() {
    var largePictTag;
    largePictTag = this.getElementsByClassName("innerBox")[0];
    largePictTag.style.visibility = "hidden";
}


function savePicsForSlideshow() {
    var innerBoxes = document.getElementsByClassName("innerBox");

    for (i = 0; i < innerBoxes.length; i++) {
        checkBoxlargePict = innerBoxes[i].getElementsByTagName('input')[0];
        if (checkBoxlargePict.checked) {
            var imgTagSrc = innerBoxes[i].getElementsByTagName('img')[0].src;
            imgUrlList.push(imgTagSrc);
            var spanTagText = innerBoxes[i].getElementsByTagName('span')[0].innerHTML;
            imgTextList.push(spanTagText);
        }
    }

    if (imgTextList.length > 0) {
        newWindow(500, 600, "slideshow.htm");
    }

}

function newWindow(width, height, filename) {
    var windowProperties;
    windowProperties = "top=100,left=100,toolbar=no,location=no,status=no,menubar=no,scrollbars=no,resizable=no,width=" + width + ",height=" + height;
    if (windVar != null) if (windVar.closed == false) windVar.close();
    windVar = window.open(filename, "", windowProperties);
}
```

Please excuse my programming and English grammar shortcomings. I'm new to javascript. 
//Henrik, Göteborg, Sweden.

Answer (score 0):

At the beginning of the savePicsForSlideshow function, empty out each array.

```
imgUrlList.length = 0;
imgTextList.length = 0;
```

Comment: Splendid! I tried that earlier but was confused by css-class switch that is made when checking the checkboxes. Obviously the new class will be visible as long as the checkbox is checked. Your solution works perfectly.

Comment: There's another issue...In function showLargePict() checking the checkbox changes the css class. This works fine. However, to have the new class implemented, you have to move the pointer away from the LargePict. I would rather have the switch made directly on checking the box, no matter where the pointer is. Any suggestions?

Comment: So you'd like to change the class while the largepict is showing? You'll need to use a click listener on the checkbox.

Answer (score 0):

You can check if thw window is close with the property closed of the object window

```
if(window.closed)
{
array.length = 0;
}
```